# AndEngine missing exception package

Tags: java, android, package, andengine, missing-features

To start off, I decided to start using [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) after making a few games using the default Android SurfaceView class, so I searched on Google on how to install AndEngine and I found a tutorial saying to create a project then import the AndEngine project + gradle settings and I did all of that stuff. Next, after gradle finished compiling it starting complaining. Basically the errors say about 2 missing packages: `org.andengine.exception` and `org.andengine.system`.

Here's a screenshot of the project view ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRXw4.png)):
[image: image-missing-packages]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a bug (which should be fixed later) in the IntelliJ IDEA (Android Studio is IntelliJ + Android SDK bundled together). The problem is caused by the importing system, which gives a warning about the path it if contains a space:

```
"C://Users/Username/A Folder/YourProjectFolder"
                     ^
```

The warning says that importing may not copy some files if the file path contains a space. To fix this, remove the imported project from the modules list, then delete it from the disk. Next, if you use Gradle also remove it manually from `settings.gradle`. Then move your project to another location (or rename the folder(s) by replacing " " with "-" or "_" eg. "A folder" to "A_folder") which has no spaces and start Android Studio, select `Open existing project` and browse to project's location.Finally re-import your project and it should have all files.

Source: `import-summary.txt` after importing the project in a location with a space in its path.